# Efficient way to unescape HTML escape characters WITHOUT external library

Tags: java, html, string, escaping

Now if I want to convert HTML escape characters to readable `String` I have this method:

```
 public static String unescapeHTML(String text) {
        return text
                .replace("&#8482;", "™")
                .replace("&euro;", "€")
                .replace("&#32;", " ")
                .replace("&nbsp;", " ")
                .replace("&#33;", "!")
                .replace("&#34;", "\"")
                .replace("&quot;", "\"")
                .replace("&#35;", "#")
                .replace("&#36;", "$")
                .replace("&#37;", "%")
                .replace("&#38;", "&")
                //and the rest of HTML escape characters
                .replace("&amp;", "&");
 }
```

My goal is not to use any external library like Apache (`class StringUtils`), etc.
Because the list is quite long - more than 300 chars - it would be nice to know what would be the fastest way to replace them?

Comment: This approach would take too much runtime. I would say to use a `StringBuilder` and parse the `String` manually. If you happen to encounter a `'&'`, then analyze until the next 5 chars or until read a `';'`, then parse this symbol for the expected char. To ease the development and maintainability, you can store all the escaped strings into a `Map<String, String>` to easily map the characters.

Comment: Hmm.. I have to do some testing.

Comment: In fact, after some review, this is the approach used by [`StringEscapeUtils#unescapeHtml`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.java#StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) (which oddly you don't want to use).

Comment: I noticed that some sites using `&#039;` instead of `&#39;`. So my solution is wrong. @Luiggi Mendoza - I thought before about similar solution, I will try to implement it soon

Answer (score 0):

Using Patterns and Matcher. if you want avoid the calculation/adjustment on buffer length, you can also keep the difference between two strings in some datastructure and use it instead of calculating buffer length at run time. like { -4,-4,0,-4} . Since buffer length is just returning the instance variable, i did used buffer length here.

```
private final static Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\&(.*?)\\;");
    private final static HashMap<String, String> patterns = new HashMap<>();
    static{
        patterns.put("&amp;", "&");
        patterns.put("&#33;", "!");
        patterns.put("&#32;", "thick");
        patterns.put("&#36;", "$");
    }

    public static StringBuffer escapeString(String text){
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(text);
        Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(text);
        int modifiedLength = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            int tmpLength = buffer.length();
                    // To consider the modified buffer length due to replace. hold difference between old and previous
            buffer.replace(m.start()-modifiedLength, m.end()-modifiedLength, patterns.get(m.group())); 
            modifiedLength = modifiedLength + tmpLength-buffer.length();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Because of `&#39;` which could be sometimes written `&#039;` - I think more effective solution is to compare Integers - I've posted test version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21884053/2111085).

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to do it this way:

```
    private static final Map<Integer, Character> iMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {//Code, like &#32; or &#032;
        iMap.put(32, ' ');
        iMap.put(33, '!');
        iMap.put(34, '\"');
        iMap.put(35, '#');
        iMap.put(36, '$');
        iMap.put(37, '%');
        iMap.put(38, '&');
        //...
    }

    private static final Map<String, Character> sMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {//Entity Name
        sMap.put("&larr;", '←');
        sMap.put("&uarr;", '↑');
        sMap.put("&rarr;", '→');
        sMap.put("&darr;", '↓');
        sMap.put("&harr;", '↔');
        sMap.put("&spades;", '♠');
        sMap.put("&clubs;", '♣');
        sMap.put("&hearts;", '♥');
        //...
    }

    public static String unescapeHTML(String str) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(),
                tmp = new StringBuilder();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
        boolean esc = false;
        try {
            int i;
            while ((i = sr.read()) != -1) {
                char c = (char) i;
                if (c == '&') {
                    tmp.append(c);
                    esc = true;
                } else if (esc) {
                    tmp.append(c);
                    if (c == ';') {
                        esc = false;
                        if (tmp.charAt(1) == '#') {
                            try {
                                sb.append(iMap.get(Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(2, tmp.capacity() - 1))));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                sb.append(tmp.toString());//Ignore and leave unchanged
                            }
                        } else {
                            sb.append(sMap.get(tmp.toString()));
                        }
                        tmp.setLength(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
            }
        sr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UnescapeHTML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Works perfectly and the code is simple. Still testing. It would be nice to hear your comments.